# Different obj_id but equal values in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, logic, self

I'm fairly new to ruby and am practicing it.
However in this exercise I'm doing it creates two bank accounts using the same method and same values, and the program expects both to be equal.
RSpec returns this to me:

```
Failure/Error: expect(conta1).to eql conta2

   expected: #<Conta:0x3161bc8 @numero="2303-2", @nome="Jose da Silva", @saldo=1000.1, @limite=500>
        got: #<Conta:0x31615f8 @numero="2303-2", @nome="Jose da Silva", @saldo=1000.1, @limite=500>

   (compared using eql?)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
   -#<Conta:0x3161bc8
   +#<Conta:0x31615f8
     @limite=500,
     @nome="Jose da Silva",
     @numero="2303-2",
```

The content of both the accounts are the same, but there's a conflict on the object_id, how do I resolve this?

Here is the code:

```
it "Two accounts with the same data should be equal" do
conta1 = cria_conta
conta2 = cria_conta
expect(conta1).to eql conta2
end

def cria_conta(numero="2303-2", nome="Jose da Silva", saldo=1000.10, limite=500)
Conta.new(numero: numero, nome: nome, saldo: saldo, limite: limite)
end
```

Also:

```
class Conta
attr_accessor :numero, :nome, :saldo, :limite

def initialize(arr)
    @numero = arr[:numero]
    @nome = arr[:nome]
    @saldo = arr[:saldo]
    @limite = arr[:limite]
end

def sacar(valor)
    possibilidade = false
    @@valor = valor
    if valor < @saldo
        @saldo -= valor
        possibilidade = true
    elsif valor > @limite
        @saldo -= valor
        @@saldo = @saldo
        possibilidade
    end
end

def no_limite?()
    if @@valor > @limite
        return true
    elsif @@valor < @limite
        return false
    end 
end

def depositar(valor)
    @saldo += valor
end

def ==(outra_conta)
self.conta == outra_conta
```

end
end

I tried to define a a diffrent method for == but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Tip: Instead of using a forced `return`, just use the expression: `@@valor > @limite` is sufficient as the body of the function.

Comment: You may need to define `.eql?` instead of just `==`. You'll also want to ensure that two "identical" values have equivalent results from the `hash` method or your objects may not sort properly into hash tables as keys.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

I put the method name as eql? and seems I'm closer to it
However it's still returning the object_id

What do you mean by equivalent results from the hash method?
Thanks!

Comment: Check that it's actually running your custom equivalence method by throwing in a `raise` or a `puts` to be sure you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

If you wants to only compare the attributes, not the object itself, here is the example code you might start with.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :id
  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @name = name
  end

  def ==(other_person)
    self.instance_variables.each do |method|
      method = method.to_s.gsub('@', '')
      return false if self.send(method) != other_person.send(method)
    end
    return true
  end
end

p1 = Person.new(1, 'alice')
p2 = Person.new(1, 'alice')
p3 = Person.new(1, 'tim')
puts p1 == p2 # true
puts p1 == p3 # false
```